# Zoom out cause overflow

Tags: html, css

Look at the picture

[image]

This is what I see with my standard resolution (1386 x 788). Watch what happens when I try to zoom out on the Internet Explorer:

[image]

Why does this happen? How to fix it? This is the code:

```
#pages{
    width: 190px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.p {
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.i {
    float: right;
    width: 80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```
<div id="pages">
    <img class="p" src="a.jpg"/>
    <div class="i"> Lorem... </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Css:

```
#pages{
width: 190px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
position:relative;
}

.i{
width: 80px;
border: 1px solid black;
position:absolute;
right:0;
}
```

Give the position to **#pages** & absolute position to class **i** & remove **float:right** from class i and check this